# How to solve a problem while trying install a pipenv with python 3.11?

Tags: python, pipenv, python-3.11

Preconditions:

- python 3.11
- pipenv 2022.12.19

Problem:
I want to create a new pipenv virtual environment for my project with command:

```
pipenv --python 3.11
```

or

```
pipenv --python /usr/bin/python3.11
```

I have the next error:

```
Loading .env environment variables...
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /home/dev/geotek-dev/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3.11 (3.11.1) to create virtualenv...
⠇ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.11.1.final.0-64 in 227ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/geotek-dev-Rxuh4rdd, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, pkg_resources=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/root/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 57, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1637, in invoke
    super().invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 210, in cli
    ensure_project(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 541, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 474, in ensure_virtualenv
    do_create_virtualenv(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1060, in do_create_virtualenv
    project._environment = Environment(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._base_paths = self.get_paths()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 383, in get_paths
    c = subprocess_run(command)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/processes.py", line 75, in subprocess_run
    return subprocess.run(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1901, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/geotek-dev-Rxuh4rdd/bin/python'
```

I have decided that the structure of folder if different than in previous versions of python.

In python 3.9 I have folders bin, lib and pyvenv.cfg
In 3.11 I have lib, local and pyvenv.cfg

/bin/python is inside local folder, not in root level.
What should I configure to work with pipenv normally?